# response of Ajax Call

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I am doing a small form validation using ajax. The user provide a key and when the form is submitted I call an ajax method validate_key.

My function is

```
function validate_key(){
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mc_boxes', array('idmc_boxes' => $id));
    $row = $query->row();
    $download_key = strtolower($row->downloadkey);
    if($download_key == $key){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

JQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var key = $('#downloadkey').val();
        var dataString = {KEY:key};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/index.php/home/validate_key",
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the form is as

```
<form name="form" method="post"> 
   <input id="downloadkey" name="downloadkey" type="text" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I check the user provided key to the database if the key is correct allow the user to view the page and set the key in session if it is wrong give an alert msg and render the form again

How can I check for the response ?

Thanks

Comment: What's your question/issue? You check the AJAX response in your success function.

Comment: @Utkanos yes and it is giving me some html of the index page of my wamp server

Comment: Read the documentation of how your framework handles AJAX requests. You're probably doing it wrong. With fuelphp I had to set up a separate REST API to handle ajax, so maybe it's the same with codeigniter.

Comment: try `$_POST['KEY']`, in upper-case, which is the way you're posting it (`dataString = {KEY:key};`)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to **echo** from your PHP page

```
if($download_key == $key){
        echo "true";
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }
```

Then in your Ajax success handler you can check the response in your callback. Make sure you are also preventing the default action by calling the  [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function so that the page wont be posted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var key = $('#downloadkey').val();
        var dataString = {KEY:key};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/index.php/home/validate_key",
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {
                  if(msg=="true") 
                    {
                       alert("do something")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       alert("do something else")
                    }                        

            }
        });           
    });
});
```

Comment: when I submit the form and see my response it shows some html and css I cant see anything true or false in my response#

Comment: use firebuug to see to which file you are making the call to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output something to the page. If you just `return true` or `return false` nothing will get output.

So do something like:

`echo "OK"`

and then you can do this in your javascript:

`if(msg == "OK"){ .. }`

The other thing you can do is return a HTTP status code e.g.

`header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`

You can check this in your jquery. Using the first method however is more useful because you can have any number of outputs on the page, including different error messages and such.

Comment: when I submit the form and see my response it shows some html and css I cant see anything true or false in my response

Comment: For a start you're using codeigniter - you should be using `$this->input->post('KEY')` rather than `$_POST['KEY']`. You also don't have a URI segment 3. Could something from this be ruining it? What is the HTML output you see?

Comment: It is some random HTML with CSS. I can show it to you if you can come on chat_

Comment: It is the html of wamp server home page

Comment: In my function I wrote $key = $this->input->post('KEY'); and echo $key removed everything else but I still cant see the value of key

Comment: Something fundamental is wrong if you're getting the html of the wamp server home page. Try going to the web page in a browser, echo something. What do you see?

Comment: I have this directory C:/wamp/www/mediabox inside the mediabox folder i have my project, and the url I provide for my ajax call is /index.php/home/validate_key. Is it correct?